# How to update cart total on payment page dynamically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, payment-methods, grand-total

How can I update cart total on payment page in Magento 2, I tried using jQuery and PHP both, but I am unable to update cart total.Can anyone please direct me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'` in your js file and call `estimateTotals()`, something like this:

```
define(
    [  
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'OtherDependencies'
    ],
    function (totalsProvider, quote) {
        'use strict';
        //Your code here
        totalsProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());

    }
);
```